# Copy from one arrayList to another

Tags: c#, arraylist, .net-1.1

I have problem with this. 
I have one arrayList, and I want to copy some objects to another. More important, each object has a specific property, which I'm using it as filter to copy. 
Unfortunately, I have to work with .NET 1.1, so I can't use lamda expressions.

Do you have any idea to do this?
I want to make this good. I have solution, just use foreach loop, but I want to make this as good optimize as I can.

Sorry for my english.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
//Insert to list few objects
ArrayList specificList = get few objects from list using filter. For example Object.Name
```

Comment: It looks like you have lot of time.

Comment: @MuhammadKashifNadeem: How did you came to conclusion that OP has a lot of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Traditional loops for .Net 1.1

You said `but I want to make this as good optimize as I can.`

Loops are best optimizer when iterating over a collection as compared to LINQ.

Based on your example you can do this.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
//Insert to list few objects

ArrayList specificList = new ArrayList(); 

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count ; i++)
{
    if (((MyObject)list[i]).Name.Contains("ogrod87"))
        specificList.Add(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank. I did something like this, but with using foreach loop.

Answer (score 5):

I think nothing is better than a loop for filtering an array in .Net 1.1.